# XLR/TRS Combo Input jacks on a powered PA speaker

Tags: speakers, xlr

I'm looking to buy portable JBL PA speakers with mixer-to-speaker XLR cords.  My mixer accepts a female XLR for output, but on the speaker I want to buy, it says only XLR/TRS Combo input.  The Spec Sheet doesn't specify if that is a male/female connector.  Does that mean it accepts a male XLR connector (XLR/TRS Combo Input)?

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean it accepts a male XLR connector (XLR/TRS Combo Input)?

Yes. XLR/TRS Combo jacks are female. (It's difficult to see how a combined male XLR/TRS plug would work mechanically.) So a female to male XLR cable will be fine.

If you edit your question to add a link to the specific speaker model you intend to buy someone can verify the connector type.

Answer (score 0):

If cables are 'sexed' then they always transmit male to female - perhaps a little misogynistic in this day & age, but that's how it goes ;)